# How do Apple Mail and Thunderbird apps fetch emails in real time?

Tags: email, smtp, imap, pop3, fetchmail

I am trying to read my emails from a terminal using fetchmail, procmail and mutt. I can fetch my emails almost in real time using fetchmail daemon to fetch every 5 seconds over IMAP or POP. This solution works on both Mac and Linux, but I would like to know if there is a better way to do this.

I used Thunderbird and Apple Mail before, and they both fetch emails almost in real time. Are they both using fetchmail constantly? Is there a way to avoid pinging my email server every 5 seconds? Maybe a socket-based solution or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many IMAP servers support [IMAP IDLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMAP_IDLE) command.  The command allows to get "near real time" notifications about new messages in selected IMAP folder (e.g. INBOX).  You keep IMAP session open and server notifies you about new messages.

[fetchmail](http://www.catb.org/~esr/fetchmail/fetchmail-man.html) supports [IMAP IDLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMAP_IDLE).